# OpenLayers GeoLocation.getPosition() is inconsistent

Tags: openlayers, android, geolocation

In my mobile application I am using OpenLayers and trying to capture current position of the user by using GeoLocation.getPosition() method.

The method sometimes returns position and sometimes return undefined. The behaviour  is strange ! The GeoLocation object has value in it. Below is my code:

Geolocation object creation :

```
this.GeoLocationObj = new GeoLocation({
        projection: this.map.getView().getProjection(),
        tracking: true,
        trackingOptions: {
            enableHighAccuracy: true
        }
    });
```

Use of this to get the position:

```
  var position = this.GeoLocationObj.getPosition();
  this.map.getView().setCenter(position);
  this.map.getView().setZoom(18);
  this.positionFeature.setGeometry(new Point(position) )
```

What should I change?

Comment: Undefined means the device hasn't located itself or there has been an error.  As in the example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/geolocation.html you should use `this.GeoLocationObj.on('error', ...)` as well as `this.GeoLocationObj.on('change:position', ...)`

Comment: Thanks for the response , I believe device did not locate itself. I waited for few mins after enabling GPS in my phone and then the app worked fine.